# Pytorch VGG16 only returning True after training

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to modify the VGG16 model in pytorch to do a simple yes/no feature detection (to detect if 1 particular feature is in an image). To do this I modified the last layer of the VGG network to output 2 tensors instead of 1000, which I believe is about all that should be necessary to accomplish this. When I test the network with random weights/biases it is around 50% accurate as you would expect, and when I print the output layer the tensors vary pretty randomly between -1 and 1. However after a bit of training the output layer very quickly shifts to the second tensor being a positive number and the first tensor being in the negative, until doing a `max()` just returns `1` (True) every time and thinks it has detected the feature in every image.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm very new to pytorch and machine learning, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Here's the simplest, reproducable example I can manage. I did not include my training/test loaders because they load images off my local disk, but hopefully this is enough code to figure out what is going wrong:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision

BATCH_SIZE = 16
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
MOMENTUM = 0.9

def train_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    model.train()
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        prediction = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(prediction, y)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print(f"Training...{batch * len(X) / size * 100:.01f}%")

def test_loop(dataloader, model):
    model.eval()
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    correct = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataloader:
            outputs = model(X)
            predictions = outputs.data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
            correct += predictions.eq(y.data.view_as(predictions)).sum().item()
    
    print(f'Test set accuracy: {(correct / size) * 100:.01f}%')
    
network = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained=False)
network.classifier[6] = nn.Linear(4096, 2)

loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(network.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE, momentum=MOMENTUM)
```

Running `print(outputs.data.max(1))` in the `test_loop` function gives the following before/after training (I lowered the batch size to 8 here):

```
# before
# print(outputs.data)
tensor([
    [4.0089e-02, -1.2475e-04],
    [3.2431e-02, -2.2334e-03 ],
    [3.7739e-02, 5.7708e-03],
    [3.7453e-02, 1.9297e-03],
    [4.3812e-02, 5.1457e-05],
    [3.8975e-02, 6.3827e-03],
    [4.3934e-02, 6.7114e-03],
    [3.6315e-02, 8.8174e-03]
])
# print(outputs.data.max(1))
torch.return_types.max(
    values=tensor([0.0401, 0.0324, 0.0377, 0.0375, 0.0438, 0.0390, 0.0439, 0.0363]),
    indices=tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
)

# after
# print(outputs.data)
tensor([
    [-0.4314, 0.4763],
    [-0.4296, 0.4799],
    [-0.3882, 0.4378],
    [-0.4257, 0.4682],
    [-0.4330, 0.4682],
    [-0.3420, 0.3832],
    [-0.4467, 0.5142],
    [-0.3902, 0.4175]
])
# print(outputs.data.max(1))
torch.return_types.max(
    values=tensor([0.4763, 0.4799, 0.4378, 0.4682, 0.4635, 0.3832, 0.5142, 0.4175]),
    indices=tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
)
```

Comment: Try to do it like this in test () : predictions = outputs.data.max(1)

Comment: If you could please print out the prediction and y arrays to see what they are.

Comment: @Phoenix Ok, data added to my post above. Thanks for looking into it.